# Access the value of a calculated ng-bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to get the value of the ng-bind to use in my ng-class? The value of the  element is calculated in the getCellTotal function. If the value of getCellTotal is greater than 0 then I want to add a 'bold' class to the td.

Now I could call getCellTotal again inside of the ng-class, but that would be duplication and unnecessary processing as this is inside of a ng-repeat and getCellTotal would be called twice for every row.

```
<td ng-repeat="col in data.cols" ng-bind="getCellTotal(col)" ng-class="{'bold': getCellTotal(col) > 0}"></td>
```

Comment: I don't think that it in fact would be called twice ... I think Angular only has to check and update that value once and it is able to use it in the template once for each cycle rather than having to call it multiple times. I'd be more concerned about calling it for each repeating element.

Comment: Would it work if col had some property as "col.getTotal"? And you may use it as ng-class="col.class()" which would return "{'bold': col.getTotal > 0}"

Comment: I am actually going to change my approach entirely thanks to @MVCDS. The "col" is a flat multi-dimensional array. Instead of taking this directly from the back end and trying to display it. I'm going to calculate the totals before hand and then I will use "col.total > 0". This way the total is only ever calculated once.